# Is there any way to find repeating url using rewriterule?

Tags: iis, apache-2.4

My url is http://www.abctest.com/mysamples/ . I need to replace this with http://www.abctest.net/mysamples/ .
Please let me know how to write a regular expression to match the repeated pattern (www.abctest.com/mysamples) and replace it with http://www.abctest.net/mysamples using RewriteRule.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect, Change URLs or Redirect HTTP to HTTPS in Apache - Everything You Ever Wanted to Know About Mod\_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/redirect-change-urls-or-redirect-http-to-https-in-apache-everything-you-ever)

Comment: What do you gain by obfuscating the names involved? If you really think the world will end if your names are seen at least use proper names for documentation: example.com and example.net

Comment: AFAIK `RewriteRule` is an Apache configuration token, I doubt that IIS will have it, why did you use both tags apache-2.4 and IIS?

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at Apache documentation? It has your exact use case here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html#canonicalhost

```
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}"   "!^www\.example\.com" [NC]
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}"   "!^$"
RewriteRule "^/?(.*)"        "http://www.example.com/$1" [L,R,NE]
```